# Merge sort in Scala using Actors

Tags: scala, sorting, actor, mergesort

So this is the code :

```
object Main {
def main(args: Array[String]){
  var myArray = Array(5,2,7,6,8,1,15,5/*,9,10,56*/)
  var startSorting = new Starter(myArray)
  startSorting.start
  startSorting ! Begin
  var i = 0
  for( i <- 0 to myArray.length - 1){
   println(myArray(i))
  }
}
 }

 import scala.actors.Actor
 import scala.actors.Actor._

 abstract class SortArray 
 case object Sort extends SortArray
 case object FinishedSubArraySorting extends SortArray
 case object Begin extends SortArray

 class Starter(toBeSorted :Array[Int]) extends Actor{
   def act(){
     var first:Array[Int] = Array()
     var second:Array[Int] = Array()
    loop{
      react{
    case Begin =>
      var SortActor = new MergeSort(toBeSorted)
      SortActor.start
      SortActor ! Sort
    case sortedArray :Array[Int] =>
         var i = 0
         println("Sortat:")
         for( i <- 0 to sortedArray.length - 1){
             println(sortedArray(i))
         }
      }
    }
   }
 }

 class MergeSort(toBeSorted :Array[Int]) extends Actor{
   def act(){
  var finishedSorting = 0
  var thisArray = toBeSorted
  var first:Array[Int] = Array();
  var second:Array[Int] = Array();
  var sortedSubArrays = 0;
  loop{
    react{
      case Sort =>
        if(thisArray.length == 1){
          finishedSorting = 1
          sender ! thisArray
          exit('stop)
        }else{
          first = thisArray.slice(0,thisArray.length/2)
          second = thisArray.slice(thisArray.length/2,thisArray.length)
          var firstSort = new MergeSort(first)
          var secondSort = new MergeSort(second)
          firstSort.start
          secondSort.start
          firstSort ! Sort
          secondSort ! Sort
        }
      case subSortedArray:Array[Int] =>
        sortedSubArrays = sortedSubArrays + 1
        if(sortedSubArrays == 1){
            first = subSortedArray
        }else{
          second = subSortedArray
          thisArray = merge(first,second)
          finishedSorting = 1
          sender ! thisArray
          exit('stop)
        }
    }
  }
   }
   def merge(firstArray :Array[Int],secondArray :Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {

var result:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](firstArray.length + secondArray.length)
var i = 0
var j = 0
var k = 0
while(i < firstArray.length && j < secondArray.length){
  if(firstArray(i) <= secondArray(j)){
    result(k) = firstArray(i)
    i = i + 1
  }else{
    result(k) = secondArray(j)
    j = j + 1
  }
  k = k + 1
}
while (i < firstArray.length)
{
    result(k) = firstArray(i)
    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1
}
while (j < secondArray.length)
{
    result(k) = secondArray(j)
    j = j + 1
    k = k + 1
}
return result
 }
}
```

It uses 2 actors:One is for the beginning and end output and another one that is going to have multiple instances of it to merge sort the array and sub-arrays. An instance is first called with `!Sort` in order to divide the array in two and make two actors for each subArray and is also called afterwards with the resulting sorted sub-array from each of the two actors i mentioned earlier.

The problem with this code is that it manages to sort and merge only at the lowest levels(subarrays with max length 2) and then for some reasons the actors call different senders than the ones that called them so nothing happens anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when the MergeSort actors receive the sublists from their children they then send the merged lists to sender - which will be their children instead of parents.

I added a parent field to MergeSort and changed sends to use this parent - here's the modified code

```
object Main extends App {

  var myArray = Array(5,2,7,6,8,1,15,5/*,9,10,56*/)
  var startSorting = new Starter(myArray)
  startSorting.start
  startSorting ! Begin
  var i = 0
  for( i <- 0 to myArray.length - 1){
   println(myArray(i))
  }

 }

 import scala.actors.Actor
 import scala.actors.Actor._

 abstract class SortArray 
 case object Sort extends SortArray
 case object FinishedSubArraySorting extends SortArray
 case object Begin extends SortArray

 class Starter(toBeSorted :Array[Int]) extends Actor{
   def act(){
     var first:Array[Int] = Array()
     var second:Array[Int] = Array()
    loop{
      react{
    case Begin =>
      var SortActor = new MergeSort(toBeSorted,self)
      SortActor.start
      SortActor ! Sort
    case sortedArray :Array[Int] =>
         var i = 0
         println("Sortat:")
         for( i <- 0 to sortedArray.length - 1){
             println(">"+sortedArray(i))
         }
      }
    }
   }
 }

 class MergeSort(toBeSorted :Array[Int],parent:Actor) extends Actor{
   def act(){
  var finishedSorting = 0
  var thisArray = toBeSorted
  var first:Array[Int] = Array();
  var second:Array[Int] = Array();
  var sortedSubArrays = 0;
  loop{
    react{
      case Sort =>
        if(thisArray.length == 1){
          finishedSorting = 1
          println(this + " sending up "+thisArray.mkString("[",",","]"))
          parent ! thisArray
          exit('stop)
        }else{
          first = thisArray.slice(0,thisArray.length/2)
          second = thisArray.slice(thisArray.length/2,thisArray.length)
          var firstSort = new MergeSort(first,self)
          var secondSort = new MergeSort(second,self)
          firstSort.start
          secondSort.start
          firstSort ! Sort
          secondSort ! Sort
        }
      case subSortedArray:Array[Int] =>
        println(this + " received " + subSortedArray.mkString("[",",","]"))
        sortedSubArrays = sortedSubArrays + 1
        if(sortedSubArrays == 1){
            first = subSortedArray
        }else{
          second = subSortedArray
          thisArray = merge(first,second)
          finishedSorting = 1
          parent ! thisArray
          exit('stop)
        }
    }
  }
   }
   def merge(firstArray :Array[Int],secondArray :Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {

var result:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](firstArray.length + secondArray.length)
var i = 0
var j = 0
var k = 0
while(i < firstArray.length && j < secondArray.length){
  if(firstArray(i) <= secondArray(j)){
    result(k) = firstArray(i)
    i = i + 1
  }else{
    result(k) = secondArray(j)
    j = j + 1
  }
  k = k + 1
}
while (i < firstArray.length)
{
    result(k) = firstArray(i)
    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1
}
while (j < secondArray.length)
{
    result(k) = secondArray(j)
    j = j + 1
    k = k + 1
}
return result
 }
}
```

Comment: I've found out in the meantime that i was using sender and sending it back in the child thread :P but thank you very much for your answer...it's important that other people dealing with such issues see this fix ;)